# What is the punishment for necrophilia according to authentic references?

Tags: fiqh, sharia, sex, punishment, hudud

Is there any reports/narrations, fiqhi opinions or sharia manuals which mention the punishment for necrophilia in Islamic law if there is one?

Comment: Please avoid posts that are one liners.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, intercourse with a corpse is covered in fiqh. The punishment is a Tazir according to the Hanafis and the dominant opinion of the Shafi'is and Hanbalis. And it is the Hadd of Zina according to the Malikis.

> وكذا وطء المرأة الميتة لا يوجب الحد ويوجب التعزير
>
> <sup>— [Bada'i al-Sana'i](https://shamela.ws/book/8183/1765)</sup>

> أو كان إتيان ميتة في قبلها أو دبرها حال كونها أو كونه غير زوج فيحد بخلاف لو كانت زوجا
>
> <sup>— [Hashiyat ad-Dasuqi](https://shamela.ws/book/21604/1946#p1)</sup>

Comment: Brother, I have a question. Do you need 4 witnesses to implement the tazeer in this case?